# i want to know what is the error in this code

Tags: php

i want to generate that Url

https://MyWebSiteUrl/order-received/thank-you/?key=wc_order_l58l4LPNKIgXB&order_id=2762

i have tried that code

```
// Return thankyou redirect
    return array(
        'result' => 'success',
        'redirect' => get_site_url( $order ).'order-received/thank-you/'.$order->order_key&order_id=.$order->id.' 
    );
```

but it gives me syntax error

can any body help in that ?

Comment: The quotes and concatenation for the "redirect" value look incorrect. It seems like you may want: `get_site_url($order) . 'order-received/thank-you/' . $order->order_key . '&order_id=' . $order->id;`

Answer (score -1):

there's an extra apostrophe (') at the end of line 4

Comment: can u please specify which one . 
because when i delete the last one 
The same error appears